# Selenium unstable results

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, headless-browser

I'm using Selenium with Python and headless Chrome driver to scrape all images from this website: https://www.redbubble.com/shop/game+of+thrones+t-shirt?ref=search_box. To summarize the code I use:

```
driver.get(url)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 60000)")
images = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "shared-components-ShopSearchResultsGridImage-ShopSearchResultsGridImage__primary--3pEtg")))
im_links = [im.get_attribute('src') for im in images]
```

Here is a valid link:

```
https://ih0.redbubble.net/image.420357355.0428/ra%2Clongsleeve%2Cx925%2C101010%3A01c5ca27c6%2Cfront-c%2C210%2C180%2C210%2C230-bg%2Cf8f8f8.lite-1u1.jpg
```

and an invalid one:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAaQAAAHMAQMAAACgJU5BAAAAA1BMVEUAAACnej3aAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAC9JREFUeNrtwTEBAAAAwiD7p7bETmAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACRA2EIAAF8YGbpAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

Sometimes nearly 50% of all links I get is invalid and sometimes the number is almost zero despite I use the same code with the same page url.
Could anyone explain this phenomenon for me? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The invalid IMG isn't really invalid, it's just more of a placeholder image. It's a base64 image. You can google to learn more about it but it's basically a text based code that is transformed into an actual image (PNG). In this case, it's too small a string to be anything of value. From what I've seen on the site, it automatically loads the IMGs for the first 16 t-shirts and the rest are placeholders. Once you scroll down (once in my experience), the rest are loaded (the placeholders are replaced with actual image URLs).

You should be able to hit the page, scroll down, and then load all URLs if that's what you are shooting for.

You can filter these out by changing your locator to a CSS selector, e.g.

```
img.shared-components-ShopSearchResultsGridImage-ShopSearchResultsGridImage__primary--3pEtg[src^='http']
```

This will only find IMG tags that have the desired class and have a `src` value that starts with `http` (which allows for both http and https).

You could go one step further and compare the number of IMG tags that do and don't have `src` that starts with `http` and see how many IMG tags aren't loaded yet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For sure I can filter the elements I get with your CSS seletor but I want to get as much loaded links as I can. As you can see I did scroll down the page before finding elements like what you just said. However, the number of links I get is unstable. How could this happen? Is it right that all the placeholder must have been replaced when I scroll to the bottom of the page?

Comment: I didn't even scroll to the bottom of the page and all the links were good for me. That's what I was suggesting at the bottom of my answer... you can compare the two lists and just wait until all the placeholders are gone and then continue the script.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by setting the page load strategy to "none" and try to get all links repeatedly until all links are valid and then stop loading the page to save time. Hope this is useful for someone.

```
def quick_load():
    global url, page_num, file
    chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chromeOptions.add_argument('headless')
    capa = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
    capa["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capa,
                                  chrome_options=chromeOptions)

    while <url is valid>:
        done_page = False
        driver.execute_script("window.open('%s');" % url)
        driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])
        while not done_page:
            driver.execute_script("window.scroll(0, 5000)")
            time.sleep(1)
            new_links = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
                "shared-components-ShopSearchResultsGridImage-ShopSearchResultsGridImage__primary--3pEtg")
            im_links = [extract(l.get_attribute('src')) for l in new_links]
            im_links = [l for l in im_links if l != 'invalid']
            if len(im_links) > 100:
                done_page = True
                driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
                <do something>
                <update url>

        driver.execute_script("window.close();")
        driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```